# Fraud detection and bot blocker for our website

Tags: java, google-app-engine

For our website, we need to check if the traffic coming in is genuine and not from BOT or any other frauds. What is the best approach we should take?

As of now, we are doing 2 things :

1. parsing the user-agent and finding if it is a bot.
2. Checking hits from ips, if hits from some IP reaches a particular limit in particular time we are blocking it.

Is there any other thing we can do, is there any service available that we can call while the hit comes to our site to check if the request is fraud or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a **Robots.txt** file in the root of your web site. It's a file which will configure which Bots has access to which pages and which bots are not allowed to crawl. So as in your case you can easily configure to block all the crawlers even including Google search engine.
Use this configuration

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

This [guide](https://en.ryte.com/free-tools/robots-txt/) may be helpful.